# startLocationUpdatesAsync is not working on the background react-native expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, location, react-native-maps

I'm trying to track my user location when the application is in the background, it works fine in the foreground and the notification is not displayed even if I added the foreground service parameter to the  here's my code startLocationUpdatesAsync, here's my code

```
 import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from "react-native";
import * as BackgroundFetch from "expo-background-fetch";
import * as TaskManager from "expo-task-manager";
import * as Location from "expo-location";

const BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK = "background-fetch";

TaskManager.defineTask(
  BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK,
  ({ data: { locations }, error }) => {
    if (error) {
      // check `error.message` for more details.
      return;
    }
    console.log("Received new locations", locations);
  }
);



export default function BackgroundFetchScreen() {
  const [isRegistered, setIsRegistered] = React.useState(false);
  const [status, setStatus] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    checkStatusAsync();
  }, []);

  const checkStatusAsync = async () => {
    await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
    await Location.requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync();
    const status = await BackgroundFetch.getStatusAsync();
    const isRegistered = await TaskManager.isTaskRegisteredAsync(
      BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK
    );
    setStatus(status);
    setIsRegistered(isRegistered);
  };

  const toggleFetchTask = async () => {
    if (isRegistered) {
      Location.hasStartedLocationUpdatesAsync(BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK).then(
        (value) => {
          if (value) {
            Location.stopLocationUpdatesAsync(BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK);
          }
        }
      );

    } else {
      Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK, {
        accuracy: Location.Accuracy.BestForNavigation,
        distanceInterval: 1, // minimum change (in meters) betweens updates
        deferredUpdatesInterval: 1000, // minimum interval (in milliseconds) between updates
        foregroundService: {
          notificationTitle: "En ligne ... ",
          notificationBody: "Mise à jour de votre position en cours ...",
        },

        showsBackgroundLocationIndicator: true,
      });
    }

    checkStatusAsync();
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <View style={styles.textContainer}>
        <Text>
          Background fetch status:{" "}
          <Text style={styles.boldText}>
            {status && BackgroundFetch.BackgroundFetchStatus[status]}
          </Text>
        </Text>
        <Text>
          Background fetch task name:{" "}
          <Text style={styles.boldText}>
            {isRegistered ? BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK : "Not registered yet!"}
          </Text>
        </Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.textContainer}></View>
      <Button
        title={
          isRegistered
            ? "Unregister BackgroundFetch task"
            : "Register BackgroundFetch task"
        }
        onPress={toggleFetchTask}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

I am using expo SDK 46 and I can't access the location at the background at all, I am in need of a solution even if it means ejecting from expo

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you are on iOS and developing using Expo Go app?
I have just ran into a similar issue and it seems that TaskManager doesn't work on iOS without a dev build.

Quoting from the docs:

> TaskManager works out of the box in the Expo Go app on Android, however, on iOS, you'll need to use a development build.

https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/task-manager/

Comment: i'm on android, doesn't work on development build

Answer (score 0):

though I am late here, I am also doing same kind of work.So two reasons it can happen:-

1. apps are already battery optimised so they are doozed off in the background after some time.Try to turn off the optimization for your app in settings
   read more on - https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.
   Use Linking.openSettings()  method from react native, it will open the app settings directly for the user
   I have pulled my enough hair to reach this conclusion :P
2. you can change the accuracy flag in the option to be highest that is 6(Location.Accuracy.BestForNavigation).Try this it will update the values the highest but it will drain more battery.Check which accuracy is correct for you.Low accuracy means the gps will trigger in more time.
3. and no need of background fetch.If task manager plus the battery optimization turned off should do the job.